# Creating a JPEG and writing its EXIF data in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I am creating an application that takes a user's hand signature, input on the Blackberry playbook. When the JPEG is created, I would like to add [Exif data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) such as the date/time to the JPEG. Does anyone know how to do this, or if it is possible?

Thanks

Phil

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything online about writing exif data, but I did find this [interesting article on reading exif data](http://www.mxml.it/index.php/2010/01/04/reading-exif-data-with-actionscript-30/).  It mentions what bytes does what.  I suggest you take that library to create something to write exif data.  Seems fairly simple, just need to set the proper tags in the ByteArray, append the image byte array between 2 tags and write to the file.

Answer (score 0):

i found two libries

[As3](http://code.google.com/p/as3-xmp-file/downloads/detail?name=as3_xmp_file_v0.2.2.zip&can=2&q=) seems to be writing it to xml, but flash builder does not take in import com.adobe.xmp.*;

[Metaphile](http://code.google.com/p/metaphile/source/checkout)